# How can convert GoogleMap API v2  code into v3?

Tags: php, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Google map v2 in to google map v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462453/convert-google-map-v2-in-to-google-map-v3)

My site is currently running Google map API v2. I would like to convert to the new Google map API v3. What changes need to be made in the following code? Recently I have received a message that v2 is disabled. So I need to modify the existing script with current functionality.

```
var maprecent;
function init_maprecent() {
function createMarker(point, myHtml) { var marker = new GMarker(point); GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() { maprecent.openInfoWindowHtml(point, myHtml, {maxWidth:200}); }); return marker; }
var markerindex = 0; var markers = new Array();
function animate_marker() {if (markerindex==markers.length) {markerindex=0;} GEvent.trigger(markers[markerindex], "click"); markerindex++; setTimeout(animate_marker, 5000);}
var bottomLeft = new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_LEFT);
maprecent = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("smallmaprecent"));
maprecent.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl());
maprecent.addControl(new GMapTypeControl(), bottomLeft);
maprecent.setCenter(new GLatLng(34.051072,-118.259961), 5);


var m0 = createMarker(new GLatLng(34.016919,-118.5010608), '<b>test</b><br>demo<br><a href=http://www.abcd.com/project_47_test.html>View project</a><br>London   ');
maprecent.addOverlay(m0);
markers.push(m0);
maprecent.addOverlay(new GPolygon([new GLatLng(34.016919,-118.5010608), new GLatLng(34.016919,-118.5010608), new GLatLng(34.016919,-118.5010608), new GLatLng(34.016919,-118.5010608), new GLatLng(34.016919,-118.5010608)], "#000000", 1, 0.5, "#444488", 0.1));
animate_marker();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

V2 isn't disabled. It is deprecated, which means it can be turned off as early as May 2013. Basically, your code needs to be re-written. There's no 1-1 mapping between V2 and V3, the code is just very different. Check out the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/